# Rearranging my folder in ascending to descending order

Tags: java, android

I have a code that creates a folder system in my app and am trying to arrange the folder such that the newest stays on top, but right now the newest folder goes under. For example the 1st should be were 4th is, while 4th should be where 1st is (it should be 1st,2nd, 3rd and 4th) but when i create it, it shows as (4th, 3rd, 2nd and 1st) .

```
  public void createNewFolder() {
    View promptsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_folder, null);
    final Dialog alertDialogBuilder = new Dialog(mContext);
    alertDialogBuilder.setContentView(promptsView);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Create new Notebook.");

    final EditText editTextName = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    final Button buttonOk = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    final Button buttonCancel = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    final View colorView = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
    final GridView gridView = (GridView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    final List<String> colors = getColorList();
    gridView.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(colors));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            colorView.setTag(colors.get(i));
            colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(i)));
        }
    });
    View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == buttonOk) {
                String folderName = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (folderName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please enter name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (colorView.getTag() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select note color.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (db.folderExistInGroup(currentGroupId, folderName)) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Folder name already exist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                db.createGroup(currentGroupId, folderName, colorView.getTag().toString());
                openCurrentGroup();
                try {
                    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextName.getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
                alertDialogBuilder.dismiss();
            } else if (view == buttonCancel) {
                try {
                    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextName.getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
                alertDialogBuilder.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(click);
    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(click);
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see where you add the tiles in the code. Could you make a [mcve], please?

Comment: @cricket_007, how do you mean, please?

Comment: Read the link, please. Cut down to  the smallest code that reproduces the problem

Comment: @cricket_007, i have done that

Comment: How so? I don't think that the InputMethodManger is part of the problem. I mean actually remove code (just for the question)